# Fill form fields based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery, laravel

A post can have many administrators, normally 4 or 5 administrators. I have a form to edit the administrators of a post.

This form has some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to a administrator of a a post.

For that I have this code:

```
@foreach($administrators $admin)
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="{{$admin->id}}" value="">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="">
          {{$admin->first_name}}
        </label>
      </div>
  @endforeach
```

Below the radio buttons, the form has some fields and I want to show in this fields the information of each selected administrator.

This part I'm in doubt how to do it. Maybe the best option is to handle this using AJAX/fetch, doing a ajax request each time a radio button is selected.

I already have the code above where each radio button id is the id of the administrator in the database.

But now do you know how to do that jquery ajax part to fill the form fields with the corresponding values of the administrator when the corresponding radio button is selected in terms of laravel controllers and jQuery? Im not finding any example on how to do this.

**Administrator controller:**

```
class AdministratorController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $administrators = Administrator::where('post_id', $id)->get();

        return view('administrators.edit')
            ->with('post', $post)
            ->with('administrators', $administrators));
    }
```

**Administrator Model:**

```
class Administrator extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'email', 'password', 'description', 'post_id'
    ];

    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: why you wanna fetch administrators again 1 by 1 when you already got them all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But so do you know to achieve properly the result I want using jQuery? Or its also dont necessary jQuery? I can pass all administrators in json from controller to the view but then how to use jQuery to fill the form fields based on the radio button selection?

Comment: Can you give us some example code of what you want? Im unsure what you wanna do exactly

Comment: For example I want that each radio button that appears in this post admins edit page shows the name of the administrator. For example if the post with id "1" has 4 administrators then it should appear on the edit administrators page 4 radio buttons. Each radio button has a name of one of the administrators fo the post. This is part is working with the "@foreach($administrators as $admin)...endforeach".

Comment: But, then when each radio button (administrator) is selected I want to show in the form fields (name, email etc) the information of each selected administrator so that the administrator details can be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a list of all administrators, then you can save those in a javascript variable and reuse them later however you want:

```
var admins = {{ $administrators }};
```

Comment: Thanks, I already used that and I get the values in the source "var admins= [{"id":1,"name":"John","email":"emailtest@test.coml","..."}] ". But then how to use jQuery to show in the form fields the info of each admin? I was trying with jQuery.each, I dont know if its a good solution but without success.

Comment: You get all the `ids` that are selected, then loop through `var admins`, match each `admin id` with `ids` and get the matches, once u get the matches, then foreach match, you create `DOM element` and populate it

Comment: Thanks I have this for now: var admins = {!!  $administrators !!}

var id = $(".radio:checked").attr('id');

for ( var i = 0; i < admins.length; i++ ) {

}. Im not understanding that part of match each admin wid ith ids. I have that for loop, what is necessary to put in it? I was trying with if(id==admins[0]){} but dont works properly.

Comment: `admins[i]` is one admin, so `admins[i].id` is one admins id